# J1 visa application: question about arrests and convictions on DS-160

Tags: usa, united-kingdom

I am a researcher based in the UK who is affiliated with a university in the UK. I have been invited to spend three months at a reputable research institute in the US later this year and have been provided with the invite form DS-2019.

I would like to start the J1 visa application process by filling out the standard DS-160 form. A few years ago when I obtained the B1/B2 visa I answered "No" truthfully to the following question on the same DS-2019 form:

> Have you ever been arrested or convicted for any offense or crime, even though subject of a pardon, amnesty, or other similar action?

However, during the visa interview at the US embassy in London, the question I was asked was phrased differently and mentioned cautions, as stated in the phrase listed [here](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/study-exchange/required-documents/):

> If you have ever been arrested, convicted and/or cautioned you are required to declare it, even if it is considered spent. The Rehabilitation of Offenders Act does not apply to U.S. visa law.

I answered Yes to the question because when I was a bachelor student I had received an official warning from the police in Scotland due to a regrettable drunken incident. I was asked to sit down at a computer at the embassy and fill out my application again, and I think I was asked to change my answer on the DS-2019 form from No to Yes (but I'm not sure, I was very stressed at the time). Fortunately, my visa was approved on the day - I had the VCU-1 form and the ACPO Police Certificate ready (showing no trace). I did not mean to hide the information about the warning - the only reason I didn't mention it on my DS-160 form initially was because, given the wording of the question, the truthful answer was (in my opinion) no - I had not been arrested and a caution/warning does not mean conviction. In fact, a "police warning" in Scotland carries much less weight than a "caution" in England and Wales, and it was known from the start that any trace of the warning would be erased after two years.

My question is, what should I do now that I have to fill out a DS-160 form again? I think I should do the same thing I did before: answer "No" to that question on the DS-160, fill out the VCU-1 form, and bring a new ACPO Police Certificate to my interview appointment. Would it be better to answer "Yes" right away?

Comment: Surely being "erased after two years" is covered by both the first "pardon, amnesty, or other similar action" and the second "even if it is considered spent"? If you answered **yes** at the earlier interview, then it's the same answer. As they say, US does not recognise the Rehabilitation Of Offenders Act. And whether it resulted in an official warning, a caution, or a conviction, you would have been **arrested**, as asked in both versions of the question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I think your first point makes a lot of sense. On the other hand, see [here](https://www.askthe.scottish.police.uk/view-category/?id=749a9f6a-06f6-eb11-94ef-002248405a51) for details about the police warnings in Scotland. There was no arrest, at least in the sense that is used in the UK. This scheme is distinctly different to cautions in England and Wales and seems on par with being issued a fixed penalty notice.

Comment: If you have no official record I *guess* you can answer NO. But if you answered YES last time, you'll have to be consistent. Perhaps you need advice from an immigration lawyer. Your account is confusing though - did you show them a 'clean sheet' and add something that wasn't recorded? Having done that, perhaps the best thing you can do is to tell the truth, and not try to weasel past the wording.